# Can't get release certificate fingerprint for Google maps API

Tags: android, terminal, cmd, google-api

I got the debug.keystore SHA1 key with no problem, but I can't get for release keystore. I keep getting this (see image) instead of the wanted list with info. I'm following the guide here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=da#the_google_maps_api_key

I use this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\keystore.keystore\ -alias jakob harteg
```

I had to use a cmd window and go to the bin folder of the Java installation folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`, otherwise I wasn't able to access the keytool. I tried moving keystore to the root folder, but without luck.

Any help? Thanks very much!

[image]

Comment: Did you try to quote the alias name: `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\keystore.keystore\ -alias "jakob harteg"`?

Comment: @Henry that gave me java.lang.exeption: Keystore file does not exist

Comment: And where is your keystore file? Maybe here: `C:\keystore.keystore` (without the trailing backslash)

Comment: just tried with my original keystore file in an other path, but then i got the same as on the picture above

Comment: But it keeps saying "Illegal Option" and the some part of the trail. What does that mean??

Comment: In the screenshot it takes `jakob` as the alias and `harteg` is then an illegal option. Quoting should help. Are you sure you used quotes around the alias name when you tried with the correct keystore filename?

Comment: @Henry Yes I'm sure i used quotes, just tried again, same thing happened

Comment: @Henry Could I copy my keystore to a usb flash drive and try this on another computer?

Comment: Yes, no problem to copy the keystore

Comment: Does the filename contain a blank? If yes, you must quote the file name as well.

Comment: oh shoot! Then i probably need the android sdk installed to use the keytool.exe right? and what's a blank? and is it okay to rename a keystore file? even if i got apps on the play store signed with it?

Comment: keytool is part of the Java installation, no need for the android sdk. The keystore filename is not relevant, you can rename and copy the file as you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that for this to work, the alias name can, for some reason, only be one word, in my case it was two.. So ended up creating a new keystore

Answer (score 0):

I created a Google Maps Android v2 API key easily using the  ZipSigner 2 app (beta release).